# The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to upload files to Oracle database Using C# vs2012. Its my first time I do so especially with Oracle. I just followed an example I found online but I got some errors before I even run the codes showing me that some of the type or name spaces don't exist.

The example I followed : [Blob Example](http://csharp-guide.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/INSERT%20BLOB)

Here are the codes that are underlined red in my Resources_to_upload.aspx.cs

```
  objCmd
  objConn
```

My code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public partial class Resources_to_upload : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void cmdUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (fileUploadDocument.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // Get the File name and Extension
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUploadDocument.PostedFile.FileName);
            string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileUploadDocument.PostedFile.FileName);
            //
            // Extract the content of the Document into a Byte array
            int intlength = fileUploadDocument.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            Byte[] byteData = new Byte[intlength];
            fileUploadDocument.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(byteData, 0, intlength);
            //
            // Save the file to the DB
            string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            object Conn = new OracleConnection(strConn);
            //
            StringBuilder strQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO RESOURCES(RESOURCES_ID, FILE_NAME, TYPE, RESOURCE_FILE) VALUES (");
            strQueryBuilder.Append("'1', ");
            strQueryBuilder.Append("'" + FileName + "', ");
            strQueryBuilder.Append("'" + FileExtension + "', ");
            strQueryBuilder.Append(" :RESOURCE_FILE)");

            String strQuery = strQueryBuilder.ToString();
            //
            OracleParameter blobParameter = new OracleParameter();
            blobParameter.ParameterName = "Resources_FILE";
            blobParameter.OracleType = OracleType.Blob;
            blobParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            blobParameter.Value = byteData;

            objCmd = new OracleCommand(strQuery, objConn);
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(blobParameter);
            //
            objConn.Open();
            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            objConn.Close();
            //
            lblMsg.Text = "Document Uploaded Succesfully";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = " Error uploading Document: " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Please help solve this issue. Thank you

Comment: Please give us a stack trace.

Comment: Hi. the error as I said is before I even run the code. but when I do it I got this error CS0103: The name 'objCmd' does not exist in the current context.and another similiar error for 'objconn'

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` is in the `System.Text` namespace.  So you can either reference it explicitly:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder strQueryBuilder ...
```

Or add a `using` directive to the file:

```
using System.Text
...
StringBuilder strQueryBuilder ...
```

As for `objCmd` and `objConn`, where do you define those?  They're not created in the code you posted.  You do create a connection object here:

```
object Conn = new OracleConnection(strConn);
```

Maybe you mean to use `Conn` instead of `objConn`?  But you don't create a command object anywhere.  You need to declare and instantiate variables before you can use them.

Comment: Thank you. the System.text was useful it solved that issue but for the others as you said there is no definition for them that's why I didn't understand them too. As I said I just followed an example online, I will put the link and I will really appreciated if you can have a look please.

Comment: @user2884405: In the example you're following the author also doesn't declare those objects.  So the code he provides won't compile.  I guess the author left it as an exercise for the reader (you) to fix that.  In any event, whether someone posted about it in a blog or not, you need to declare and create variables before you can use them.